# React scrollTo / get Y position of an element/component

Tags: reactjs, scroll, offset

The following piece of code scrolls to top and also accepts a delay:

```
const ScrollToTop = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {intervalId: 0};
  },

  scrollStep: function () {
    const top = 0;

    if (window.pageYOffset === top) {
      clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }
    window.scroll(top, window.pageYOffset - this.props.scrollStepInPx);
  },

  scrollToTop: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const intervalId = setInterval(this.scrollStep, this.props.delayInMs);

    this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
  }
});
```

How can I achieve something similar but using my main navigation? Is there a way of calculating the element's offset? I could then instead of passing **top** pass **this**.

Comment: what do you mean by using your main navigation?

Comment: @juancab I have a main navigation in my app which I want to scroll to the appropriate section on click (e.g. Home, About, Contact, etc.). I've got this working with **scrollIntoView** but its smooth behavior only works in **Firefox** and thus it jumps rather than scrolls.

Answer (score -3):

Use a library to achieve that.

Take a look at [react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll). It's a directive for basic scrolling and smooth scrolling.

[Live example](http://fisshy.github.io/react-scroll-example/basic/index.html) is available. If that works for you, [read the usage guidelines](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll#usage).

Comment: I've checked this out before (as well as other libraries). I was hopping for an approach that doesn't require a library. I'll think about it, thanks!

Comment: I would use a  3rd party library to solve this problem. It's not so mainstream to do, and a little utility like react-scroll could save you a headache. PS: If this solves your issue, I'd like to kindly ask you [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/343165) by clicking the green check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution, gives some reputation to both you & me, and It might help people experiencing a similar issue by getting your question noticed.